# Error uploading iOS binary - image file icon_ipad.png corrupt

Tags: cordova, appmobi

I am trying to update an iPad/iOS app in the Apple App Store and received an e-mail which included:

"Corrupt Image File - The image file icon_ipad.png appears to be corrupt. Your icon must not be an interlaced PNG file."

The app is built using AppMobi which uses PhoneGap and I have no idea what icon_ipad.png is as AFAIC we don't include such a file. I've Googled to no avail.

Neville

Answer (score 1):

icon_ipad.png is an image that you upload to the build system in step 2. It sounds like your image is corrupt. Can you send me your appName so I can take a look at the image in the cloud?  support at appMobi.com

Comment: I've emailed details as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the image you uploaded to the build system (Large Launch Icon (72w x 72h : PNG)) in Photoshop, then tried to resave it. It defaults to Interlaced. The simple solution is to just resave your png, this time picking None, not Interlaced. Then upload the new image and rebuild your app.